# Spree Extension Scaffold

Tags: spree

I have created a a spree application and used one existing extension **spree_news** by cloning it to my spree application folder, now when i try to create a scaffold or a resource inside the **spree_news** extension  by trying:

> wapnil@swapnil-pc:~/ecommerce/spree_news$ rails generate scaffold oerp
>   Pname:string Pdesc:text Pprice:float

the following error is encountered:

```
/home/swapnil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/engine/commands (LoadError)
    from /home/swapnil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from script/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 4):

The `script/rails` file in your extension is wrong and should be [this](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/1-0-stable/cmd/lib/spree_cmd/templates/extension/script/rails.tt). This is due to a bug in Spree that will be fixed in the next release.